# How to delete a file from the file system in Linux when I don't have permission?

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

I re-installed ns2, but didn't delete a file from the filesystem with path:

```
/usr/bin/ns
```

So when I type on my terminal:

```
which ns
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/ns
```

Instead of the path I have set which is:

```
/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/ns
```

This is in my home directory `me`. How should I delete the file in the filesystem with a similar name? The properties of this file says in permissions that I do not own this file, so I cannot change the permissions.

I can't run my tcl scripts if the path isn't set correctly and to set it, I need to delete the duplicate `ns`. How to get permission to delete? And how to delete it using my terminal?

Comment: Can you sudo on this machine?

Comment: yes i can sudo on this machine.

Comment: Then you can `sudo rm /usr/bin/ns` and even better `sudo cp /home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/ns /usr/bin`

Comment: @DigitalChris If `ns` depends on other files being in paths relative to it, or if it's a symlink or hardlink, the `sudo cp ...` line can break it and stop it from working. I don't know what `ns` is, but unless it's just that one binary (I highly doubt it from the allinone having a `bin` directory), that operation is not safe.

Comment: Uhh... how do you reconcile "yes I can sudo" with "I don't have permission" ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The user likely has a poor understanding of file permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't *required* that you delete the file `/usr/bin/ns` in order to make `which` and `exec` automatically execute `/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/ns`.

All you have to do is put `/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin` on your `$PATH` *prior to* `/usr/bin`.

Here's the **wrong** way to do it:

`export PATH="${PATH}:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin"`

In this case, `/usr/bin` (by default on `$PATH`) will be *earlier* in the `$PATH` expansion than the one you want, so you'll execute `/usr/bin/ns` when you run `ns` or `which ns`.

Here's the **right** way to do it:

`export PATH="/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:${PATH}"`

Now, just typing `ns` or `which ns` will point to the one you want, without having to delete anything.

**Update:** If you want, to avoid modifying your `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc` or similar, you can create a bash script wrapper around your tcl script that modifies the path first. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:${PATH}"
tcl ...
```

If you want to delete `/usr/bin/ns` *anyway*, and you do not have access to the `root` account or the ability to `sudo` (or to put yourself in the `/etc/sudoers` file), and `/usr/bin/ns` is owned by `root` and is not world-writable, then you are mostly out of options for deleting this file, *unless*:

- You are able to boot the computer into another operating system (live CD, live USB, etc.), obtain root in *that* OS, and delete the file;
- You execute some sort of exploit (**I do not recommend this if you do not own the machine!**)

Basically, "how do I delete a file I don't have permission to delete" is a loaded question: the question assumes that the owner of the machine *wants* you to delete this file, and *wants* to give you permission. If the owner of the machine *isn't **you***, you should not be even asking this question, and we will not help you break or intrude into someone else's machine. It'd be like saying "how do I drive this car on the street when I don't have the keys?" -- yeah, good luck with that.

Comment: you mean that if i export PATH this way in my .bashrc file, my tcl script should work? because i dont want to export PATH everytime i run  script after logging into terminal. i want to make path change permanent.

Comment: He really should remove that binary if he has no need to execute it from that directory anyhow, but I do agree with the rest of your assessment. Also, even if he did it the wrong way, `which` would show the other locations.

Comment: You can indeed put it into your `~/.bashrc` file; as long as you're only executing your tcl script as your user, you'll be fine.

Comment: @DanielChateau What implementation of `which` do you have? On my machines, `which` only ever shows *the first* instance of the found executable. So for instance if you had `/usr/bin/bash` and /usr/local/bin/bash`, and both directories were on `$PATH`, it would only list the one that occurs **first** as a result of a path-search for the executable. Similarly, if you `chmod -x` one of the instances, that instance will be "hidden" from `which` finding it. That's how it's always worked on my boxen....

Comment: Updated answer with a little guide for how the OP might write a bash script wrapper for this without even having to modify their `.bashrc`.

Comment: @allquixotic You are correct, I was thinking of `whereis`, not `which`. Please excuse the mix up.

Comment: my bashrc has these PATHS:                                      export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
export TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIBRARY:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library

Comment: do i just put :$PATH at the end of each?

Comment: Why would you put $PATH at the end of *each*? It's an *append* operation. You'll end up with the original/default $PATH list included multiple times in the middle of your PATH. No. Only append $PATH **one time** at the very end of the list. And don't append it to any of those environment variables except for PATH! For LD_LIBRARY_PATH and TCL_LIBRARY, you don't need to change what you already have there.

Comment: As a point of general interest, `which -a` will list all matching entries in your path but, more importantly, [don't use `which`, use `type` (or `type -a`) instead](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22222).

Answer (score 1):

Quick glance at my own `/usr/bin/` shows that directory is owned by root. Assuming you can use `sudo` or `su`, either `rm` as `root` or use `chown` to change it to your username or group.

You can become root user by simply issuing the `su` command. In most terminals you'll see your prompt change from $ to a # indicating you're currently logged into the terminal as root. Make sure when you're done as root you `exit` out immediately as to not inadvertently issue other commands with such elevated access to the file system which could lead to you doing damage to your file system. From there you can use `rm` on `/usr/bin/ns`.

The ***safer*** route is to use the `sudo` command to allow for a command to be run as root for just that instance by issuing your `rm` command like so:

`sudo rm /usr/bin/ns`

Comment: how to use chown or rm as root, can you please elaborate a bit? will i be able to delete it this way?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: i did what u said and now after i type which ns, it gives me nothing. Is that a good sign?

Comment: That at least means you've removed `ns` from `/usr/bin/` correctly, but you still need to follow what allquixotic noted in his answer to fully resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

@allquixotic is absolutely right. You *can't* delete a file if you don't have the permissions to do so and the only way would be to *get* the permissions by an exploit or by using something like `sudo` if you have the right. That's the whole point of filesystem permissions.

Now, another approach that you can use to get around this is to set up an alias. Open your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`) and add this line:

```
alias ns='/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/ns'
```

Bash aliases are evaluated *before* the `$PATH` is searched so this will make the `ns` command point to your locally installed version by default.